# How to fix ("ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 16 layers into a model with 0 layers")

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, vgg-net

I'm using vgg16 like this:

```py
model = VGG16()
data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)

vgg16 = VGG16()

model = Sequential()

#Converting VGG16 into Sequential model
for layer in vgg16.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)

#Freezing all layers except last layer for transfer learning
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

#Adding custom softmax layer
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

#Compiling our model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), batch_size=32, epochs=3)

model.save('model.h5')
```

and when I tried to load this model in another py file..:

```py
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

**I'd already tried load_weights and throws an error too**

... returns this error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 16 layers into a model with 0 layers
```

What should I do to load this model to make my predictions?

versions: keras 2.2.4 tensorflow 1.14.0

Comment: Check Keras version first and if you are bound to use the old one, try to define the input_shape. Look [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11072#issuecomment-418257081).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10417

There are three options: 1. Recreate the model architecture and use '`load_weights`'. This is good if you only want to do predictions. 2. Downgrade to Keras version `2.1.6.` 3. A workaround available at this link https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10417#issuecomment-435620108. I adapted this for VGG16. This updates the h5 file.

```
def fix_layer0(filename, batch_input_shape, dtype):
    with h5py.File(filename, 'r+') as f:
        model_config = json.loads(f.attrs['model_config'].decode('utf-8'))
        layer0 = model_config['config']['layers'][0]['config']
        layer0['batch_input_shape'] = batch_input_shape
        layer0['dtype'] = dtype
        f.attrs['model_config'] = json.dumps(model_config).encode('utf-8')

fix_layer0('model.h5', [None, 224, 224, 3], 'float32')

loaded_model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: I'm sorry i've posted the wrong version.. I'm using load_model and it returns that error

Comment: Which version of Keras/tensorflow you're using?

Comment: keras 2.2.4 tensor 1.14.0

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been solved in newer versions of TensorFlow

simply upgrade your TensorFlow:
pip install tensorflow --upgrade

Comment: If you're sure a new version includes a fix, it would be useful to provide a link to the changelog which confirms this.